# Perl www::mechanize

Tags: forms, perl, perl-module, www-mechanize

İ am very new to perl module `www::mechanize` and I want to functionalize snp id. For that I have to make a web crawler, but i am having difficulties . İ dont know how to use field names or how to assign values.
I have to access this website: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/ .Please tell what are the fieldnames here. Thanks in advance.
I mean to specify a field name here I have to put the snp id for search.
I am not understanding what to do.
Kindly anybody help.

```
   use WWW::Mechanize;
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;

   my $snp = 'rs111';
   my $URL = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/SNP/";

   $mech->get($URL);

   $mech->submit_form(
   form_number => '1',
   fields => {

   'ID' => $snp,
    },
    );
    print $mech->content();
```

Answer (score 5):

Use a tool such as the [Web Developer add-on for Firefox.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/)

The page has three forms.

1. ```
   Id       Name     Method   Action
   ------   ------   ------   --------------------------------------------------
   Search   Search   post     http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/coreutils/dispatch.cgi

   Elements
   ========
   Id       Name     Type     Value      Label   Size   Maximum   Length
   ------   ------   ------   --------   -----   ----   -------   ------
   Search   db       select   13
   term     term     text                for     24
   Search   submit   submit   Go
   Search   SITE     hidden   NcbiHome
   ```
2. ```
   Id   Name    Method   Action
   --   -----   ------   --------------------------------------------------
        frmGo   get      http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/query.fcgi

   Elements
   ========
   Id   Name       Type     Value     Label   Size   Maximum   Length
   --   --------   ------   -------   -----   ----   -------   ------
        db         hidden   Books
        cmd        hidden   Search
        term       input                      12
        Submit     submit   Go
        doptcmdl   hidden   TOCView
   ```
3. ```
   Id   Name       Method   Action
   --   --------   ------   --------------------------------------------------
        searchID   post     getID.cgi

   Elements
   ========
   Id       Name         Type     Value          Label   Size   Maximum   Length
   ------   ----------   ------   ------------   -----   ----   -------   ------
            searchType   hidden   adhoc_search
   sub_id   sub_id       input                   ID:
   IDtype   Type         select   dbSNP_rs
            submit2      submit   Search
            reset        reset    Reset
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i have to use perl mechanize module specifically.

Comment: huh? The Web Developer add-on gets you the information you requested (and that I posted). Now use the names it/I priovided with WWW::Mech.

Answer (score 0):

There are developer tools for each web browser: [Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) for the Opera (it's built-in and I use it most of the time), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for the Firefox etc. I most of the such tools you need to right click on the element you need to look at and select something like "Inspect element with..."[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have to use perl mechanize specifically. Actually when i have to select an option from dropdown menu by using select statement . I received the follownf error no input for ths field found

Comment: Secondly one thing more how can i coem to know about the field names and form name, actually i have to fetch the data from three more websites can u plz tell the way. thnk you so much in advance. I am in great trouble kindly plz help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this version (your form is named Search and field name you need is `db`):

```
$mech->submit_form(
    name => "Search",
    fields => {
        db => $snp,
    },
    button => "submit",
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Now İ receive this error "Error POSTing http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/coreutils/dispatch.cgi:" And can you plz tell me how can i know abt field name and form name, i just dont understand where are the field names in a website

Comment: Sorry I am asking very basic questions , i just want to ask when i run my program through print mech->conten() i get the html page in return how can i get the output result file

Comment: Use `$mech->save_content("file.name")` for this